# limiting access to stored files

Tags: java, security, encryption, file-storage

I'm writing an application that stores some files in Java.
The application has 4 hierarchical access levels (each access level **can** view lower and **can't** view upper level).
I need to protect these stored files against two scenarios:

1. Direct access from disk itself by everyone.
2. Access to files without appropriate access level.

I'm not going to use OS users to limit access (Access levels should be managed in application).
each files can has more than 1GB size so I think encrypting each file is not a good idea. (?)

What is the solution?

Comment: Do you also need to protect the files from access from outside your application, i.e. do people have access to the disk? If so, you have to look into OS services for protection.

Comment: @Jochen: As I mentioned in scenario #1, yes; I need to protect files from outside of application. yes they do have access to disk but while they are logged in the OS. I solved physical access by encrypting the entire drive using TrueCrypt.

Comment: If they have access to the files through the OS, the best you can achieve is to have confidentiallity (encryption) and protection against *undetected* change (MAC or HMAC). Even then you have the problem of where you want to store the keys. If you cannot safely store the keys (encrypted with some kind of token or within protected application code) the best you can achieve is obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to prevent access to the files then you need to use OS file permissions.

you can use encryption to prevent other users reading the contents of the files, but that will not stop them moving / deleting / overwriting them.

at least you will need to create an OS account for your application which is the only account that can access the files. then you can manage your different access levels within the app as you wish.

Comment: Thanks; It seems to be the simplest and most straight forward.